# Can tx and rx pins on the uno be used like regular digital pins?

Tags: arduino-uno

The uno has digital pins marked 0-13.

0 is marked as rx and 1 is marked as tx. 
Can these two pins be used as regular digital pins if i am short of digital pins?

Comment: If you are short of digital pins you can aways use the analog pins. They also work as digital pins.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes you can perfectly use these 2 pins as long as your program does not use `Serial`.

EDIT: Serial data over USB goes through copper traces connected to the rx and tx pins, connecting them to the USB to serial converter chip.

Comment: My program is using serial, but pumping it through the usb. Not out of the rxtx pins. Is this still a problem?

Comment: It is the same: USB data is passing through RX/TX pins :-(

Comment: Ok thanks for your great answer and clarifying these points

Answer (score 3):

Also you will probably want to ensure these wires are not connected when programming the Arduino. Otherwise you may have problems.

Answer (score -1):

You can, but it will disable the serial port.

Comment: No, it's the other way around: the serial port has higher priority. When you enable it with `Serial.begin()`, you are disabling the normal port operation (`pinMode()`, `digitalRead()` and `digitalWrite()`). With one exception: you can set the RX pin to `INPUT_PULLUP`, rather than `INPUT`, which is the default. C.f. the datasheet of the ATmega328P, especially the sections _Alternate Port Functions_, _Data Transmission – The USART Transmitter_ and _Data Reception – The USART Receiver_.